# Nexus 5 auto connects to wifi with wifi off

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-5

In some areas of my house I have weak wifi so I prefer to use 4g by turning wifi off, but it will automatically turn itself back on and reconnect. How do I set it such that if I turn off wifi it stays off until I turn it back on?

Below is a list of all the installed apps (pm list packages from the terminal emulator)

```
com.wunderkinder.wunderlistandroid
sworkitapp.sworkit.com
com.google.android.backup
com.fivehundredpx.viewer
org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon
com.stackexchange.marvin
com.android.packageinstaller
com.android.providers.userdictionary
com.audioaddict.di
com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs
com.google.android.launcher
com.laurencedawson.reddit_sync.pro
com.mylottos.results
com.google.android.apps.cloudprint
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
com.google.android.apps.fitness
com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
jackpal.androidterm
com.android.managedprovisioning
com.flavionet.android.camera.pro
com.google.android.play.games
com.amazon.storm.lightning.client.aosp
com.google.android.feedback
com.redbox.android.activity
com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer
eu.kowalczuk.rsync4android
com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
com.google.android.inputmethod.korean
com.aa.android
com.touchtype.swiftkey
com.android.inputdevices
org.zwanoo.android.speedtest
com.android.bluetooth
com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel
org.mozilla.firefox
com.imdb.mobile
com.android.printspooler
com.redbend.vdmc
com.google.android.ears
am.sunrise.android.calendar
com.google.android.apps.maps
com.reidwolcott.expocalc
com.vladlee.easyblacklist
com.android.vpndialogs
com.stuck_in_customs.stuck_on_earth
com.cube.arc.pfa
com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.weather
com.google.android.apps.enterprise.cpanel
com.android.server.telecom
com.sony.playmemories.mobile
com.google.zagat
com.somafm
com.google.android.tag
com.android.defcontainer
com.google.android.gm
com.android.systemui
com.android.nfc
com.android.providers.calendar
com.android.vending
com.fitbit.FitbitMobile
com.HBO
com.android.providers.downloads
com.lenstag.app
com.google.android.gsf
com.blizzard.bma
com.amazon.kindle
com.google.android.youtube
com.android.htmlviewer
com.adobe.reader
com.android.location.fused
in.zendroid.hyperfocal
com.anydo
com.hp.android.printservice
com.dropbox.android
com.android.providers.contacts
com.google.android.apps.enterprise.dmagent
org.coursera.android
com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app
com.koushikdutta.tether
com.datacolor.caprica
com.lge.update
com.google.android.androidforwork
nexbit.icons.moonshine
com.google.android.apps.googlevoice
com.google.android.apps.magazines
com.google.android.setupwizard
tv.twitch.android.viewer
com.google.android.apps.genie.geniewidget
com.lastpass.lpandroid
com.google.android.apps.paidtasks
com.google.android.contacts
com.google.android.maps.mytracks
com.Fraom.Gel
com.android.captiveportallogin
com.google.android.gms
com.kandravy.minimalico
com.devhd.feedly
com.google.android.configupdater
com.google.android.keep
com.andrewshu.android.reddit
com.soundcloud.android
com.android.pacprocessor
com.google.android.GoogleCamera
com.automatic
com.delta.mobile.android
com.google.android.apps.helpouts
com.google.android.apps.books
com.google.android.inputmethod.pinyin
com.android.facelock
com.ifthisthenbreak.alongways
com.android.stk
com.google.android.gsf.login
com.android.backupconfirm
com.ultimateguitar.tabs
com.android.providers.downloads.ui
com.android.externalstorage
com.yingwen.photographertoolspro
si.modula.android.instantheartrate
com.mailboxapp
com.google.android.apps.onetoday
kov.theme.nox
radiotime.player
com.smugmug.android.cameraawesome
com.fivemobile.thescore
com.android.calculator2
com.android.shell
com.yelp.android
com.android.chrome
com.android.proxyhandler
com.google.android.marvin.talkback
com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro
com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
com.rwoar.pfacalculator
com.prey
com.gombosdev.ampere
com.kelby.one
com.momocode.shortcuts
com.android.keychain
com.qualcomm.timeservice
de.lehe.google.news
com.google.android.apps.photos
com.android.dreams.basic
com.usaa.mobile.android.usaa
com.go.launcherex.theme.kxnt.glasklart
com.android.browser.provider
com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets
com.google.android.apps.messaging
jp.co.canon.ic.eos.eosremote
pl.vipek.camera2
com.google.android.street
com.match.android.matchmobile
com.deviantart.android.damobile
org.openintents.filemanager
com.android.phone
com.google.android.gallery3d
com.google.android.apps.plus
com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.hindi
com.android.certinstaller
android
com.android.phasebeamorange
com.android.providers.telephony
com.evernote
com.google.android.webview
com.paypal.android.p2pmobile
com.cubesoft.zenfolio
com.findsdk.apppermission
com.muhanov
com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
la.droid.qr
com.google.android.gm.exchange
com.google.android.music
com.vanguard
com.squareup
com.meetup
com.google.android.email
com.ryanmkelly.me.flatro
com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel
com.google.android.apps.authenticator2
com.google.zxing.client.android
com.google.android.talk
com.adobe.lrmobile
com.cube.arc.trc
com.android.documentsui
com.niksoftware.snapseed
com.android.settings
com.android.sharedstoragebackup
com.cube.arc.fa
com.google.android.deskclock
com.android.wallpapercropper
com.ubercab
com.google.android.calendar
com.konylabs.capitalone
com.hilton.android.hhonors
com.qualcomm.shutdownlistner
jp.co.omronsoft.iwnnime.ml
com.google.android.dialer
com.google.android.videos
com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
com.android.providers.settings
com.calciumion.themepicker.app
com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore
com.trello
com.google.earth
com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.slides
com.benx9.palmtree
com.aimenrg.dof
com.amazon.mShop.android
com.google.android.apps.docs
com.audible.application
com.androbros.puzzle2048eng
com.triggertrap 
com.android.mms.service
com.google.android.tts
com.caynax.hiit.pro
com.lge.SprintHiddenMenu
com.android.providers.media
com.android.musicfx
com.garmin.android.apps.connectmobile
com.google.android.partnersetup
```

Comment: You have to go to Settings -> WiFi -> Advanced -> 'Scanning always available' set this to off. This would suffice.

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel it is off though and it still does this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps that may turn the Wi-Fi on. I know of one app that can turn on your Wi-Fi when at a specific location. There may be some app turning your Wi-Fi on, I suggest seeing if you can find which app is doing that.

Comment: Once upon a time I had an app that would turn wifi on/off based on cell tower information, but I don't seem to have that installed anymore and none of the apps I have seem to do that. I'm currently trying to export a list of my installed apps, but I'm still at a loss.